# How do i make it so i have to press multiple buttons in python keyboard?

Tags: python, module, keyboard

I want to make it so I have to press multiple buttons in python keyboard module, but the method I tried doesn't work.

```py
import keyboard
keyboard.on_press_key(["shift + b"], lambda _:spam())
```

Any help?

Comment: as I know `on_press_key` is only for single key - and it doesn't matter if it has `Shift` or not. Maybe you should use `hotkeys` (which can have many keys) - `keyboard.add_hotkey(...)`. Or you should use `on_press_key("b", ...)` and run function which check if `Shift` is already pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know `on_press_key` is only for single key - and it doesn't check modificators like `Shift`,`Ctrl`,`Alt`. It would have to run code which checks if `Shift` is already pressed.

import keyboard

```
def test(event):
    #print('test', event.modifiers)
    if 'shift' in event.modifiers:
        spam()
    
keyboard.on_press_key("b", test)
```

But for combinations you have `hotkeys`

```
keyboard.add_hotkey("shift+b", spam)
```

And it has to be `"shift+b"` without spaces.

---

Doc: [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard)